# Determine the Laurent expansion of $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(2-z)}$ for different regions in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have tot determine the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(2-z)}$ for the regions $|z-1|>1$ and $0<|z-2|<1$.

I already know what to do for the regions $|z|<1$, $1<|z|<2$ and $|z|>2$ by using the partial fraction decomposition $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{2}{2-z}$, but I fail to determine it with the other given regions. I hope somebody can help me out with this.

Comment: you can set $z-1 = u$ for the first region then $z-2 = u$ for the second and determine the Laurent series with respect to variable $u$, then plug $u = z-1$ (and $z-2$) back into these series.

Comment: I thought about that, but I then do not know how to determine the laurent series of $\frac{2}{u}$ for example.

Comment: $\frac{2}{u}$ is already Laurent series itself. remember that, you are writing Laurent series of $f$ near the point $1$ (and $2$), so you will end up with something like $(z-1)^n$, not $z^n$

Comment: I still don't get it. Would you mind giving me a more comprehensive answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let $z-1 = u$, then $|u| > 1$ and $\frac{z}{(z-1)(2-z)} = \frac{u+1}{u(1-u)} = \frac{2}{1-u} + \frac{1}{u}$.

As $|u| > 1, \frac{2}{1-u} = \frac{-2}{u}.\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{u}} = \frac{-2}{u} \sum\limits_{n \geq 0}\frac{1}{u^n} = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac{-2}{u^{n+1}}$.

Thus, $\frac{z}{(z-1)(2-z)} = \frac{2}{1-u} + \frac{1}{u} = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac{-2}{u^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{u} = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac{-2}{(z-1)^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{z-1}$.

The second region is similar.